# Centos 7 Force BIOS (Not Fast Boot)

Tags: centos7, bios

I have a `CentOS 7` box that has `quickboot` installed.

Is there a way I can get into the `BIOS` again?  Is there a startup key combination, or a file I can edit to get to the `BIOS` menu on reboot?

Update:  `Fast Boot` is an **ASRock** option in the startup `UEFI` utility (the `BIOS` menu at startup).  As it stands now, upon reboot, the `Linux` prompt loads within seconds.

Comment: What do you mean by "quickboot"? A quick Google search isn't turning up anything that appears relevant.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I just updated what I found out later.  I'm thinking this is an __ASRock__ issue.

Comment: Do you not see the GRUB menu, then?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by GRUB menu. The blue BIOS menu I have t seen.  I think I have to move the jumper on the CMOS for a reset.

Answer (score 0):

Not a full solution, but it got me into the `BIOS` to change the setting.

- power down for minimum 15 seconds, disconnect, open box, jumper on `CMOS Reset` jumpers (left of battery) for 5 seconds minimum (< 10 seconds), then reconnect and boot.

The issue I have now is that my `OS` won't boot.  I'm trying settings for the two `SSDs` in `RAID` and `non-RAID` formats.

I was told in another forum that disconnecting the drives forces the `BIOS` to come up, which would have avoided all this.